# Changing default MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS laravel 10 fortify

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-mail, laravel-fortify

i am using laravel 10 with auth package fortify, i've added 2 new vars to .env file
`MAIL_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT_MANAGER="accountmanager@app.io" MAIL_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT_MANAGER_NAME="${APP_NAME} account manager"`
I want to send reset password, verifyemail email and everything that is part of the accunt management with this email address. How i can do?

I have changed the config\mail.php file from this:

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
```

to this:

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
        'accountmanager'=>[
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
            'from' => [
                'address' => env('MAIL_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT_MANAGER', 'hello@example.com'),
                'name' => env('MAIL_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT_MANAGER_NAME', 'Example'),
            ],

        ],
```